# Get specific rasters (with date string in rasternames) from FGDB in to the list

Tags: arcpy, raster, list, datetime

I have a FGDB with many rasters. The raster name contains date at the end(YYYYMMDD). See example rasters bellow. I can get all rasters in to the list with wildcard. That is not the issue. I want to get rasters between a specific period. for exammple from_date:20220514 to_date:20220621
Is this possible?

Example rasters:

```
.................
moisture_20220513
moisture_20220514
moisture_20220515
moisture_20220516
.................
.................
.................
.................
moisture_20220619
moisture_20220620
moisture_20220621
moisture_20220622
moisture_20220623
.................
.................
```

What i have tried:

```
import arcpy
import datetime


# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\test_raster.gdb"

# Get and print a list of GRIDs from the workspace
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("moisture*", "GRID")

for raster in rasters:
    print(raster)
```

with the above code i am getting all rasters starting with "moisture".

**i want to get list of rasters from FGDB**

**from date: 20220514**

**to date: 20220621**

I have tried bellow code also

```
start_date:"20220514" 
end_date:"20220621"

correct_raster_files = [x for x in arcpy.ListRasters("*", "GRID") if x >=  "*_" + start_date and x <= "*_" + end_date ]
print(correct_raster_files)

After printing I have got empty list []
```

**Any ideas to solve this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `datetime` even though you import it. Split the raster name on the "_" character and convert the last part to a `datetime` then compare to start and end dates.

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime

from_date = datetime.strptime("20220514", "%Y%m%d")
to_date = datetime.strptime("20220621", "%Y%m%d")

# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\test_raster.gdb"

# Get and print a list of GRIDs from the workspace
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("moisture*", "GRID")
in_date = []
for raster in rasters:
    date_string = raster.split("_")[1]
    date_time = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m%d")
    if from_date <= date_time <= to_date:
        in_date.append(raster)

print("\n".join(in_date))
```

Output:

```
moisture_20220514
moisture_20220515
moisture_20220516
moisture_20220619
moisture_20220620
moisture_20220621
```